# Unable to Stack Build a Haskell Project when using postgresql-simple

Tags: postgresql, haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, libpq

```
Machine: M1 MacBook Pro 

Stack GHC: 9.0.2 (but I have also tried multiple 8.X versions)
```

For context, I am very new to stack and cabal. I have done MOST of my Haskell work in a pure LeetCode/Math setting, and not much in real world scenarios, like making sql connections.

I have a test project where I am trying to make a connection to a postgresql database using postgresql-simple, but I am unable to get the program to compile due to some weird clang gcc linker error (error details below)

This is my main.hs file:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Database.PostgreSQL.LibPQ

connectionInfo :: ConnectInfo
connectionInfo = defaultConnectInfo
        { connectHost = "some server"
        , connectDatabase = "some database"
        , connectUser = "some unique user name"
        , connectPassword = "some complex password"
        }

main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- connect connectionInfo
    mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn "select 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int])
```

Specifically these two lines are the lines that cause the compilation issue, if I comment them out, everything works fine:

```hs
conn <- connect connectionInfo  
mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn "select 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int])
```

and here is the error I get when running stack build:

```sh
> stack clean
> stack build
#. . . (OMMITED FOR BREVITY)
  "_PQftype", referenced from:
      _Ls2X7E_info in libHSpostgresql-simple-0.6.4-9DaeedHkXWRH0l488TVAtv.a(FromRow.o)
      _Lc301R_info in libHSpostgresql-simple-0.6.4-9DaeedHkXWRH0l488TVAtv.a(FromRow.o)
      _Ls2shM_info in libHSpostgresql-simple-0.6.4-9DaeedHkXWRH0l488TVAtv.a(PQResultUtils.o)
  "_PQfformat", referenced from:
      _Ls1Y29_info in libHSpostgresql-simple-0.6.4-9DaeedHkXWRH0l488TVAtv.a(FromField.o)
  "_PQfreemem", referenced from:
      _LckG6_info in libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3-IkP6G59sk5XEvvBwPSqWYy.a(LibPQ.o)
      _LckIK_info in libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3-IkP6G59sk5XEvvBwPSqWYy.a(LibPQ.o)
      _LckL9_info in libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3-IkP6G59sk5XEvvBwPSqWYy.a(LibPQ.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building package some-project-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      /Users/someMacOsUser/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.4.1.0_ghc-9.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.4.1.0 build lib:some-project exe:some-project-exe --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
>
```

it seems my issue has something to do with compiling postgresql-simple and postgresql-libpq?

These are my dependencies:

```yaml
#(package.yaml)
dependencies:
    - base >= 4.7 && < 5
    - text
    - filepath
    - containers
    - postgresql-simple >= 0.6.4
    - postgresql-libpq >= 0.9.4.3
    - aeson
```

```yaml
#(stack.yaml)
extra-deps:
   - postgresql-simple-0.6.4
   - postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3
```

I have tried manually supplying different packages in the Extra Dependencies section.
I have also tried different Resolvers (manually supplying a GHC 8.X.X LTS).

I am expecting it to return:

```hs
Only {fromOnly = 2} -- select 1 + 1 => 2
```

Any help on resolving this compilation error would be helpful.

**UPDATE**
I also have a laptop that runs archlinux. I was able to run my exact code on stack ghc 9.0.2.
I did have to install libpq on arch as well, but as soon as I did that everything worked.

This leads me to believe this has to do something with my MacBook being an Arm machine, and for some reason the compiler doesn't know how to handle linking libpq?

Comment: postgres-simple depends on `libpq` library, which is an external dependency. i.e. a `C` library which you need to have installed in your system. The error does not point to this problem but It is feasible that the problem is here. In debian-based systems you can run `sudo apt install -y libpq-dev`. In MacOs I don't know but you can google "how to install libpq"

Comment: I do have libpq installed using ```brew install libpq```.